# cURL request returns 404 for api.natera.com

Tags: php, curl

I am using cURL to get and post some json array to api.natera.com
When I am curl Get to https://api.natera.com/ it returns 200 OK.
but to `https://api.natera.com/2.0/jobs/sequencingRun` it gives 404 Not Found.
When I am using OPTIONS to above link instead of GET, it returns 200.

Please help

Comment: a) Post your curl commands exactly. b) Talk to the API providers.

Comment: That's not a public api, so there aren't docs we can look at to know or guess at issue

Answer (score 0):

That endpoint returns the following json response...
{"error":"Not Found"}
I don't know of a webserver that returns this response as a standard 404, so you are probably hitting the service you are trying to hit. Is there an API doc for this endpoint? You might need to include some query string args or something.

Comment: This should be a comment.